# Read a character from file with C and compare to check if it is an asterisk

Tags: c, strcmp

I am trying to finally learn C but I am getting stuck with some stupid things. In this case, what I am trying to achieve, is to create a program that will manage phone contacts. The "tool" allows to insert a contact or delete and search for contacts. It uses a binary file in C and I configured the code so it will work with **records and fields of variable length**. In this case, my records are in the following format (there is a header that points to the last deleted record):

```
record_length|name|phone|
```

My current requirement is that when I choose to delete a record, I will overwrite the record contents with:

```
record_length * next_record*
```

This token `*` identifies that the record status is deleted. Until this point, I am ok with the program. The problem is about a last function of the program, which is `compress file`.
   I  want to add a function that will read the whole file and copy the *VALID* records to a new file, removing any unused space (for example, if I delete a record with length of 20 and later or if I overwrite the record with a new one with length 10, the process will keep the last 10 junk chars in the file).
   The function is actually pretty simple, the basic idea is:

- Go to the beginning of my file and read the header to store it in a temporary variable
- `fread` from file with `sizeof(int)` to get the record length until `fread` returns `NULL` (end of file)
- `fread` one single character

  - `if this char == *`, I want to skip the record and move to the next
  - `else`, go back 1 position in the file and copy the valid chars of the record to the new file.

  And now comes the stupid question: how do I verify, wether the character is an asterisk? I am so frustrated because I was able to implement the whole code, the only thing that I am missing is this this implementation. Here is what I am trying to do:

  ```
  #define MAX_REGI_SZ 70
  int main (void) {
    char registro[MAX_REGI_SZ];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    fread(registro,sizeof(char),1,in);                   
    if (strcmp(registro,"\*")) {                         
       /* move to the next record */
    }                                                    
    else {
      /* valid record, copy it over to the new file */
    }                        
  ...
  }
  ```

  I have already tried to compare with `"*"`, tried to declare a char token and then `make token = "*"` and then use token in the `strcmp`, tried to compare `registro == "*"` directly, this is simply impossible to achieve. I have been trying to find a solution to this for days and haven't found anything anywhere, so I am giving up and asking here to the masters of C.

Comment: Yes, and it gives me "Operation between types "char" and "char*" is not allowed."

Comment: Also make sure you use single quotes around `*` for it to considered a `char` instead of  `char*`

Comment: How can you `strcmp` the input when you only input 1 character? The var `registro` is uninitialised, has no string terminator, so it's **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: hmmm, i didn't know of that. well, for my surprise, i just understood strcmp. at first i thought it would return 1 in case of both strings being the same so now i tried this:

  if (!strcmp(registro,"\*")) {                         

instead of this:

  if (strcmp(registro,"\*")) {                         

i haven't noticed the slight detail of using double quote or single quote, i will try to use '*' instead of "\*" later. i just don't get the difference of both cases

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `fgetc()`.

```
#define MAX_REGI_SZ 70

int main (void) 
{
   char registro[MAX_REGI_SZ];
   ...
   ...
   ...
   registro[index]=fgetc(/*Your file pointer*/)                 
   if (registro[index] == '*') // or if (registro[index] == 42)
   {                         
       /* move to the next record */
   }                                                    
   else 
   {
     /* valid record, copy it over to the new file */
   }                        
   ...
  }
```

Note instead of `if(registro[index] == '*'` you could also use `if(registro[index] == 42)` that is compare it with the `ASCII` value of the character.[ASCII Values Link](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)